# Ruby Gem "mechanize" missing libxml2 on Mac OS X 10.7.2 (Lion)

Tags: macos, ruby, gem, libxml

I'm trying to run a Ruby script, so I installed Ruby together with Ruby gems on my Mac OS X 10.7 system. The script requires the Rubygem "mechanize" so I tried to install it by using:

```
sudo gem install mechanize
```

However this fails with an error:

> Error installing mechanize:   ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   extension.
>
> /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb checking for libxml/parser.h... no
>   ----- libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with
>   installing dependencies.

So it seems libxml2 is missing or not found. What is the easiest way to install it? It's already in `/usr/lib`:

```
/usr/lib/libxml2.2.7.3.dylib 
/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib 
/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
```

I have to add that I don't know anything about Ruby programming, I just want to run a little script I found at github.

Comment: Yes there are:
`/usr/lib/libxml2.2.7.3.dylib`
`/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib`
`/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib`

Comment: I mean, you shouldn't need `sudo` to install gems, but that can't possibly be the problem. You actually have `libxml2` already installed. I unfortunately can't test this, as I'm not on Lion. The issue is not with `mechanize` itself, but with `nokogiri`, so if you can install that first, `mechanize` should install fine. Some people mention installing `libxml2` themselves using [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/746966) (but updating all mentions of 2.7.7 to 2.7.8 before). That could be worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Xcode and re-build libxml2 and libxslt manually like described [here](http://rtmatheson.com/2011/09/installing-ruby-1-9-2-on-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/)
    tar xzvf libxml2-2.7.3.tar.gz 
    cd libxml2-2.7.3
    ./configure --with-python=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.3/
    make
    sudo make install

```
cd /usr/local/src
curl -O ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxslt/libxslt-1.1.20.tar.gz
cd libxslt-1.1.20
./configure
make
sudo make install
```